# @WebMvcTest - How to configure security so the test can run?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to unit test my Spring Controller service that returns a String. I want to assert that the expected url name is correct but my test always returns a null url. I am using SpringRunner, @WebMvcTest and MockMvc for this.

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
public class CompanyInfoController {
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @Autowired
    public CompanyInfoController(final CompanyService companyService) {
        this.companyService = companyService;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("@someService.hasRole('" + Constants.MY_ROLE + "')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/companyInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCompanyInfo(final HttpServletRequest request, final 
        Model model) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Getting Company Info");
        final CompanyInfoDTO companyInformation = loadCompanyInfo(request);
        model.addAttribute("companyInformation", companyInformation);
        return "companyInfo";
    }

    private CompanyInfoDTO loadCompanyInfo(final HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        final Account someAccount= (Account)request.getAttribute("someAccount");
        if (null != someAccount) {
            final CompanyInfoDTO companyInformation = companyService.getCompanyInfo(someAccount);
            return companyInformation;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unable to retrieve this account details.");
        }
    }
}
```

Controller Test -

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebMvcTest(CompanyInfoController.class)
    @Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
    public class CompanyInfoControllerTest {
        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @MockBean
        private CompanyService companyService;

        @MockBean(name = "someService")
        private SomeService someAuthorizationService;

        @Before
        public void setUp(){  
            Mockito.when(someAuthorizationService.hasRole(Constants.MY_ROLE))
                        .thenReturn(true);
        }        

        @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void canInvokeGetCompanyInfoServiceSuccessfully() throws Exception{
            CompanyInfoDTO dto = new CompanyInfoDTO();
            final Account mockAccount = new Account();
            mockAccount.setId("12334");


        Mockito.when(companyService.getCompanyInfo(Mockito.any(Account.class)))
            .thenReturn(dto);
        RequestBuilder request = get("/companyInfo")
                    .requestAttr("someAccount", mockAccount);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/companyInfo"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

        @Test
        @WithMockUser
        public void forwardsToCompanyInfoPageSuccessfully() throws Exception{
            CompanyInfoDTO dto = new CompanyInfoDTO();
            final Account mockAccount = new Account();
            mockAccount.setId("12334");

          Mockito.when(companyService.getCompanyInfo(Mockito.any(Account.class)))
            .thenReturn(dto);

            RequestBuilder request = get("/companyInfo")
                    .requestAttr("someAccount", mockAccount);

            mockMvc.perform(request)
                    .andExpect(redirectedUrl("companyInfo"));
        }
    }
```

The test keeps failing with this error -
java.lang.AssertionError: Redirected URL 
Expected :companyInfo
Actual   :null

Not sure what I am missing!
I do not see the debug statement inside my controller getting printed. But my controller is not mocked out. Is my security mocking correct? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update - This is what I see in my logs -

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /companyInfo
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = []
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.cmt.controller.CompanyInfoController
           Method = public java.lang.String org.cmt.controller.CompanyInfoController.getCompanyInfo(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws java.lang.Exception

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", X-Frame-Options:"SAMEORIGIN"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found

at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:36)
```

I see Http response code 200. I am assuming it authenticates just fine. But why would my model and view be null?

Comment: You aren't redirecting so why should it expect a redirect url.

Comment: The other alternatives I have tried doing after mockMvc.perform are - 
 - .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString() . That too did not work. Any pointers to what I should be asserting?

Comment: Why should you get content as a `String`... You return the name of a view, then assert that.

Comment: I have tried that as well, it says ModelAndView does not exist

Comment: What have you tried? Start with the status and check if that is ok, if it is something else, your setup is wrong to begin with. If that works, then assert the name of the view and content of the model.

Comment: I believe, I have not configured the security properly, for which it is not actually invoking the service. I have another Test where I am checking if the http status is Ok. It says its 200 OK but it does not log the debug statements within the controller service.

Comment: That it doesn't log doesn't say anything, could be your logging setup. If your security wasn't setup you would get a 401 or 403 and thus not ok and your test would fail. You can try however to specify the role you need in the `@WithMockUser`  annotation.